# Partitioning a large PostgreSQL table doesn't yield performance increase, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-partitioning, postgresql-12

Working with a very large date-based transactions table, we decided to use *partitioning* to get a performance boost. The strange thing is, we don't see big performance gains.

I'm trying to figure out using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` what Postgres is actually doing, but I find it hard to read/determine what the problem seems to be.

Some specs:

- Using PostgreSQL 12.12 64 bit on Ubuntu.
- Partition transactions_202210 has 40118032 rows and is 9.9 GB in size (+ 14GB indexes).
- Table transactions_old has 289618048 (estimated) rows and is 71 GB in size (+ 91GB indexes)

I have executed the same query twice, once on the partitioned data for October, and once on the old table.

This is the newly partitioned table, partitioned by `book_date`:

```
explain analyze select * from transactions
where book_date >= '2022-10-01' and book_date < '2022-11-01'
and logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'
LIMIT 90000
```

This takes a little under 9 seconds to complete. This is the Query Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..350527.14 rows=90000 width=321) (actual time=117.259..8467.530 rows=90000 loops=1)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.56..380543.90 rows=97707 width=321) (actual time=4.469..8340.750 rows=90000 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using transactions_202209_logical_account_id_book_date_idx on transactions_202209  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=319) (actual time=4.456..4.461 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'::uuid) AND (book_date >= '2022-10-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (book_date < '2022-11-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
        ->  Index Scan using transactions_202210_logical_account_id_idx on transactions_202210  (cost=0.56..380046.78 rows=97706 width=321) (actual time=5.803..8322.708 rows=89999 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'::uuid)
              Filter: ((book_date >= '2022-10-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (book_date < '2022-11-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning Time: 46.393 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 7
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.650 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 32.546 ms, Emission 77.547 ms, Total 112.743 ms
Execution Time: 8718.342 ms
```

The second query, performed on the old, unpartitioned table:

```
explain analyze select * from transactions_old
where book_date >= '2022-10-01' and book_date < '2022-11-01'
and logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'
LIMIT 90000
```

This takes a little under 4 seconds to complete, using the Query plan below.

```
Limit  (cost=569.58..53494.83 rows=13569 width=315) (actual time=244.439..3720.348 rows=44038 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transactions_old  (cost=569.58..53494.83 rows=13569 width=315) (actual time=244.437..3713.977 rows=44038 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'::uuid) AND (book_date >= '2022-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (book_date < '2022-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Heap Blocks: exact=5938
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IX_transactions_logical_account_id_book_date""  (cost=0.00..566.18 rows=13569 width=0) (actual time=241.483..241.484 rows=44038 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((logical_account_id = 'some_uuid'::uuid) AND (book_date >= '2022-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (book_date < '2022-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning Time: 18.052 ms
Execution Time: 3724.277 ms
```

It seems like the first query uses the partitions, so that's good (I *do* see that 1 row is appearantly coming from another partition, but that would not impact performance in a big way, I assume).

But I would expect a faster result. I'm not sure how to read the analyze output to conclude something.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions as well as the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones unfortunately this is a commercial application, so I can't give out too many details. I understand this limits the help I can get. Hopefully the information given leads to some experts giving some tips or another way formward.

Comment: Did you change the data when partitioning? Or perhaps did you use a different `logical_account_id` when testing? The second plan only returned half of the rows that the first one did, which could account for a big portion of the difference in time (it was a bit more than twice as fast). Also, if effectively all of your results came from a single partition then I'm not sure what particular performance benefits it would provide for that query? Finally, what are your goals/targets here in terms of execution time?

Comment: This is not weird at all.  Partitioning is generally about manageability, not about performance.  I see no good reason to think this would have gotten much faster. I suspect all of your time is going to IO.  You should turn track_io_timing on, and then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to check that.  Also, having a LIMIT with no ORDER BY is usually a bad sign.

Comment: What is the correlation of book_date (given by pg_stats.correlation) for your raw table and for the relevant partition of the partitioned table?

Comment: I don't know what the state of the buffer was when you ran these queries. If you run the queries back to back, there is a good chance that the data was loaded into the buffer for the 2nd query making it faster. Sharing explain (analyze, buffers) would be great to clear that confusion/assumption

having index definitions would also be great as it can widely impact performance. Would like to know what is order of columns in your index definition?

Comment: @user20042973 was correct, these queries return a different number of results. It seems we overlooked something and not all data is present in the old unpartitioned database, so the results are skewed. Still figuring out what happened exactly, but other data queried by months give consistently better result in the partitioned tables.